# ng-Controller syntax -- what is the alias for?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I don't understand how to use the controllerAS syntax. In my demo app, I have a view controller with the following syntax:

```
ng-controller="mainController as ctrl"
```

Within the scope of that HTML, I have this code:

```
<h2>{{ ctrl.person.name }} <small>{{ ctrl.person.jobTitle }}</small></h2>
  <p class="lead"><a href="mailto:{{ ctrl.person.email }}">{{ ctrl.person.email }}</a></p>
```

My expressions won't print despite having the controller alias set as 'ctrl'. The expressions will only print if I remove the 'ctrl' alias from the 'mainController' controller.

I think I am not understanding how scope works. Here's my js script at the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var directory = angular.module('directory', []);
directory.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('roster.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.people = data;
      $scope.peopleOrder = 'name';
    });
  }
]);</script>
```

My [**plunker link is here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/4cr7Ix43HPaqDbxWvZcc?p=preview). Can someone help show me the reasoning? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need an alias for your controller? You can access scope variables directly from your view, you don't need the controller name before variable name, just use people variable directly without ctrl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-skinny-angularjs-controllers) will point you in the right direction for solving your problem.

The gist of it is that with the controllerAs syntax, you no longer use `$scope`, but `this` instead.

First off, your router has to be made aware:

```
.state('main', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '...',
    controller: 'mainController',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
})
```

Then, databinding happens on `this` rather than `$scope`, so this snippet:

```
$scope.people = data;
$scope.peopleOrder = 'name';
```

...becomes:

```
this.people = data;
this.peopleOrder = 'name';
```

Then, in your view, you can access the data:

```
<pre>{{ people }}</pre>
```

I assume people is an array so you will have to iterate using [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).